# Looping a function through numeric objects in the workspace

Tags: r

I have a multitude of objects coming from a multi-pairwise mantel test. There are all called tmp1,tmp2,...,tmpn and have the following structure:

```
str(tmp1)
 num [1:2, 1:1326] 0.348 0.001 0.221 0.001 -0.133 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "statistic" "signif"
  ..$ : chr [1:1326] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```

test stats are in tmp1[1,], pvalues in tmp1[2,].
I want to apply the following code to each object called tmp... in the workspace:

```
FDR.tmp1 <- p.adjust(tmp1[2,], method = "fdr")
f1 <- approxfun(tmp1[2,],FDR.tmp1, rule=2)
pval1 <- uniroot(function(x) f1(x)-.05, c(1,.001))$root
pdf("tmp1.pdf", height="5", width="5")
sig1 <- length(which(tmp1[2,]<pval1))
plot(tmp1[1,], tmp1[2,])
abline(h=0.05, col="red")
abline(h=pval2, col="blue")
dev.off()
```

This basically adjusts the p-values of the test-statistics to multiple testings, and calculates the significance treshold according to FDR *(if you have any objections in terms of the validity of this approach, please tell)*.
I want to store each of the functions and adjusted p-values with a name that resembles the tmp-object they are related to.

Thank you!
Sorry for not providing sample data, i dont know how to dput a subsample of these large tmp objects.

Comment: Why are the `tmp*` not all together in a list? Use `yourtmps <- mget(ls(pattern = "tmp\\d*"))` to fetch them from the global environment and loop over the list components.

Comment: ^ there's your answer. You may want `pattern="^tmp\\d*$"` though, in case you also have an object like `another_obj_tmp2_blah` in the environment and want to avoid sweeping that up as well